# Sending JWT token with browser get requests

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I'm working on a java spring security application and I want to implement sateless authentication with [Json Web Token(JWT)](https://jwt.io/).

In case of ajax requests, there is not any problem and I can send generated token inside request header in this format:

```
Authorization: Bearer jwtHeader.jwtPayload.jwtSignature
```

The problem is sending `GET` requests with clicking `<a>` tags. Suppose I have a `/my-orders` url that responsible for getting a normal html page and I want to secure it for just authenticated users. **When a user click on a link or paste an api get url directly in browser address bar, his request always fails, because there is no jwt token in the get request.**

Is there any way for sending jwt with browser get requests?

Answer (score 1):

Using XMLHttpRequest you can add Http header to a GET request, but you cannot add a http header to an anchor tag GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Add jwt as query parameter in every link of your tags.

e.g [My Orders](/my-orders?jwt=eyJhbGNiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIwIsH0.KsKmQOZM-jcy4l_7NFsrWn)

```
<a href="/my-orders?jwt=eyJhbGNiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIwIsH0.KsKmQOZM-jcy4l_7NFsrWn">My Orders</a>
```

and in the backend expect the jwt in the query parameter of get or post request.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But in your solution, I need to open the url and validate jwt token **manually** and this means I ignore spring security rules.

Comment: i don't think you need to do it manually. Try to look at implementation of BearerTokenExtractor class and its extractToken method. There you will see it is looking for a parameter with name "access_token".